# No such module 'mailcore'

Tags: swift, smtp, mailcore2

I had tried to integrate the `mailcore2-ios` pod for `smtp` purpose after installation when I tried to give import `mailcore` it says no such module '`mailcore`' even inside that pod file no file directory present but pod file installed. Please any help me for how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add pod like

```
pod 'mailcore2-ios'
```

Then run a command like `pod install`
after a while it looks like this.

[image]

if you want to use this pod just write

```
import Pods_MailcoreDemo
```

And you are ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Product > Clean**, restart XCode then **Build** project again.

If it doesn't work, check your Podfile and run **pod install** or **pod update** commands.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Xcode after clearing derived data.